# OnCompletionListener not working once mediaplayer is reinitialized

Tags: android, media-player

```
mySound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
 @Override
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.release();...
 }
```

The code works fine if mySound is not changed. But when mySound is released and reinitialized, the code no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted by Google:

> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

after call `release()`, and if you need use this again, you must create new instance of `MediaPlayer` and re-initialization, also including `setOnCompletionListener`.

```
mPlayer.release();
mPlayer = null;  

mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
...
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: It seemed that after the reinitialized, not set `setOnCompletionListener`. Surely it will not work because you've created a new references and you must re-initialize.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: even if you reset media player than also you need to set it again